# How to pick up glyphs in SVG fonts by their unicode attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, unicode

I'm trying to extract specific characters from SVG fonts designed for music engraving. Music fonts usually contain a large set of characters (> 3500) but I only need a small subset of them in order to cache glyphs in the compressed form for a quickly access.

A typical glyph node usually looks like that:

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe050;" horiz-adv-x="621" d="...">
```

I therefore need to pick up required glyphs by their "unicode" attribute. I think it should be possible to do with querySelector or jQuery.

What I don't get at all is how the selector should look like. The following (very naive) selector doesn't work:

```
var myGlyph = document.querySelector("glyph[unicode=e050]");
```

A further complication in this case is the fact that there are glyphs having more than one unicode codepoint:

```
<glyph unicode="&#xe058;&#xe880;" horiz-adv-x="671" d="...">
```

I undestand that I need to create the proper selector for the both cases. I'm a beginner in this area and don't fully understand the selector grammar in the existing documentation.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution for the above mentioned problem. I'll post it below in the hope that it will be useful.

The selector for the first case looks like that:

```
var myGlyph = document.querySelector('glyph[unicode="\ue050"]');
```

In the second case one just need to concatenate unicode codepoints:

```
var myGlyph = document.querySelector('glyph[unicode="\ue058\ue880"]');
```